# How to cancel/override effect of chrome.tabs.insertCSS

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension uses `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` method for modifying page styles. Sometimes I need to turn modifications off, is there way to do it without page reloading?

I know one way to do it: inject script with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` instead which then creates `style` element. Then I can cancel modification by removing inserted `style` element.

But may be there is more direct solution.

Comment: Check out a solution I suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533820/how-do-i-remove-an-injected-css-file/18537071#18537071 TL;DR wrap your in `body.customclassname` and toggle that class name on `body` through JavaScript.

Comment: The above should read "wrap your **styles** in `body.customclassname`".

Comment: Ok, I understand your solution, thanks. However, it requires JavaScript to set body class. And if I inject JavaScript then I'd better just create style node.But I can use `body:not(.disabled-custom-style)` to avoid injecting JavaScript until it is required to disable style.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Either way you'll need some JavaScript. (you might be able to insert CSS that cancels the first one, but that would be hard if not impossible for that to work on any random page) What I like with my solution is that once the CSS is inserted in the page, the toggling requires minimal code. Adding and removing a `<style>` node feels a bit heavy-handed to me. (even though it makes little difference in the end)